# Sharing of php source files without sharing passwords to SQL server

Tags: php, mysql, security

We are using an external programmer to implement some code, simply to try and distribute the workload. This project is using online MySQL server, also when we are working on the local files. The MySQL login is stored in a php file. When i share the source code, I would prefer not to share the login information before i trust the external programmer. The site will not run properly without the database access.

What is the smartest way to link to the MySQL database?

So far, I tried uploading the config php file to a url and include that. I found that i could `echo file_get_contents('$url')`, but that did not do the job. The php.ini is set to allowing external url. I did not find any other relevant suggestions.

Any suggestions?

BR, Emil

Comment: Why not put the credentials into a seperate file which you don't share? Why not use techinques like dotenv?

Comment: If it is not shared, how will they connect to the databse then?

Comment: If you don't want to share the credentials, the application might not work - exactly. That's why you should either share the credentials or not. Usually, you would use fixtures to provide a sample set of data such that developers can start their own, private instance of the database and not interfere with the production data

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files. **Credential storage is a solved problem.**

Comment: In general database credentials **DO NOT EVER GO IN YOUR SOURCE CODE** and should **NEVER BE CHECKED INTO VERSION CONTROL**. You must be vigilant about keeping separation between code and credentials. If you ever mix these together you put yourself at severe risk. An `.ini` or `.env` type file that's kept **OUTSIDE OF THE WEB ROOT** is absolutely a must.

Comment: "The php.ini is set to allowing external url." is a super bad idea. Remote code execution is extremely dangerous, and making it easy for people is to invite disaster.

Comment: Sorry for all the alarming text here, but these things are serious and ignoring them, or worse, being ignorant of them is how extremely bad things happen to people.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for swift reply. I had the feeling that i needed to shift to a framework. I was hoping for a simpler solution for now, as i am building a mockup prototype. I am new to php (i'm a mechatrocics engineer, not programmer, so my experience is more python, matlab and c). I wanted to outsource the task to get up and running just right with framework but so far it has worked okay just hardcoding on localhost with VScode, and was hoping to stretch that.

Comment: @tadman the php.init file was set to that by default in xampp. I didnt change it. So it concerns me that you find the default setting alarming.

Comment: XAMPP is not the kind of thing you'd ever want to deploy with. It's a development platform. Sometimes default settings are ridiculously unsafe, I've seen many examples, so always check them against recommendations for any sort of public service.

Comment: And i am developing. I just need to share the code to outsource some CSS work which i suck at. It is not a running site yet.

Comment: Nothing wrong with getting started. What's important is you adhere to some basic principles here from the start. If you do this you'll have far less to worry about down the road. If you ignore it, you'll have a huge mess on your hands, and in many cases it'll be too late to clean up because you'll already have been attacked and everything's been stolen. This is like learning basic food safety practices or electrical wiring principles. There's a lot of things you just *do not do* to avoid risks.

Comment: @tadman The plan was to make a mockup that runs with the functions and the look, and then pay a professional to make the actual code as it should be made.

Comment: But in the end, is the only viable way to either 1) make the db local for development or 2) share the credentials?

Comment: Like I said earlier, this is a solved problem in any framework. If you're just smacking together something for testing, who cares what the credentials are. Just bake them in. It's important to be absolutely clear that this is only for testing.

Comment: Yeah, but the database has other stuff too, hence my concern. So i am trying to protect other projects by not sharing the credentials.

Comment: The question has been closed although i dont think the associated question answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using some version control system** (git for example) you shouldn't store logins, passwords, api keys and other sensitive information in your code repository. Files with credentials should be ignored (added to .gitignore).

In this case when you will share your code repository with remote developer, he will not have any information about your production db credentials. (He will use his own local instance of database with his personal credentials)

**If you aren't use any version control system** (what is not recommended) and share code via archive, for example, you can replace file with credentials with some placeholders and provide instructions for developer how to replace placeholders with his own local credentials.

In both situation very possible you will need to share also a db dump. It will be good if you will have some test db for this purposes.

Comment: Hi Vladimir. Thanks for taking the time. I am using github for version control but the database is online so i was hoping for a simple method to share the credentials without him being able to actually see them, like pulling an external file from web. But it seems that is not an option - Or at least not a good one, from the comments above. I will rethink the strategy.